# links in comments in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application where I allow users to enter comments. The comments are displayed back like so

```
<%= simple_format(sanitize(c.comment)) %>
```

If a user enters the following the in the comment link this link gets appended to the end of the rails root directory. So if someone clicked on the link the would go to

```
www.somedomain.com/myrailsapp/www.blah.com
```

What can I do to correct this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to append "http://" in the href attribute of the anchor tags.

And if you aren't using it, may I suggest the [auto_link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link) helper method. It will automatically do what you are looking for.